# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please help me

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, oracle, oracle10g

I made a Boarding House system, everything was going smoothly until I found this error. When I click btnDone I want to save it to my Oracle db. I dont know why I can save boarder_id through boarderpic under dsNewRow into my tblBoarder2, but under dsNewRow2, I can't seem to save it on my other table which is tblAddItems.

I don't understand how to code this. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance. I'm actually new to coding and got interested in vb.net since last two months so my experience is quite low.

Here's my code:

```vb
Private Sub btnDone_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim picfaculty As String
        Dim filetocopy As String
        Dim newcopy As String

        filetocopy = picPath

        newcopy = Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & Form3.lblPicname.Text
        If System.IO.File.Exists(filetocopy) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(filetocopy, newcopy)
            picfaculty = Form3.lblPicname.Text
        Else
            picfaculty = "pic.png"

        End If

        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("tblboarder2").NewRow() '<--This is the part w/ the error
        dsNewRow.Item("boarder_id") = lblID.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("lname") = Form3.txtlname.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("fname") = Form3.txtfname.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("mi") = Form3.txtmi.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("age") = Form3.txtage.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("gender") = Form3.cboGender.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("occupation") = Form3.txtOccupation.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("roomnum") = Form3.cboRoomnum.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("boarderpic") = picfaculty

        ds.Tables("tblboarder2").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
        da.Update(ds, "tblboarder2")


        Dim dsNewRow2 As DataRow

        dsNewRow2 = ds.Tables("tblAddItems").NewRow()
        dsNewRow2.Item("boarder_id") = lblID.Text
        dsNewRow2.Item("Item") = "Blanket"
        dsNewRow2.Item("Quantity") = Form3.cboBlanket.Text

        ds.Tables("tblAddItems").Rows.Add(dsNewRow2)
        da.Update(ds, "tblAddItems")

        MsgBox("New Record Added to the Database", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Save")
        Me.Close()
        Form3.Close()



    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a column named `boarder_id` in `tblAddItems`?

Comment: Please try to give us a better explanation of your problem. If your exception is related to SQL execution, edit your post and add your table estructure. In addition debug your program and tell us exactly in which line is the program failing.

Comment: What line of code is throwing th exception?

Comment: I'd suggest you remove all occurrences of "Form3." as it shouldn't be necessary. If you happen to use this code on another form you could have a real mess on your hands. I'd also get rid of the .Close calls use just use Me.Close on another Exit button. Just some general comments...

Place a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through the statements one at a time to see where the error occurs.

Comment: you shouldn't place logical / model code directly in your view interruptions.

Comment: Oh @OldProgrammer the error line is 

dsNewRow2 = ds.Tables("tblAddItems").NewRow()

Right below the Dim dsNewRow2 As DataRow

Comment: @KarlAnderson Yes there is a column with that name.

Answer (score 0):

How certain are you the error is on that line?  I am suspicious of the preceding condition.  I have used similar code before and found the object reference error occurrs in the file copy:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(filetocopy, newcopy)
```

because the file already exists in the destination and its not set to overwrite. You are using the first overload.  Try using the second like this:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(filetocopy, newcopy, true)
```

And see if your error goes away.

-d